# How to hide Openlayers 4 Overlay while hover over controls

Tags: openlayers

I use sth like

```
map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
    if (evt.dragging /*or evt.target === control*/) {
        tooltipPopup.setPosition(undefined);
    }

    //get all polygon features and show info about them in popup
};
```

But when feature is behind control, popup overlaps control. It is still clickable but it doesn't look nice. So my intent is to prevent displaying popup when i hover over control similarly like above for dragging.

Comment: could you provide a minimal fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/651/ ... When you hover over zoom in or zoom out text shouldn't be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlay exists as an DOM element. so it can be tricky way to do with DOM events.
The className of default zoom control is `ol-zoom`. so you can set `mouseover`, `mouseout` event to hide and show popup.

add this code at the bottom of your fiddle:

```
var zoomControlElem = document.getElementsByClassName("ol-zoom")[0];

zoomControlElem.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  tooltipPopup.setMap();
});

zoomControlElem.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  tooltipPopup.setMap(map);
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/653/)

**UPDATE:**
To make some more related to the map, use `map.getViewport().getElementsByClassName("ol-zoom")` instead `document.getElementsByClassName("ol-zoom")`

Comment: Thanks for tip. I was searching for something more generic or included in base of Openlayers because i got multiple controls. But as long as it seems that this work fine i will use it.